# Changing background color of actionbar

Tags: android

My Android app uses a minimum SDK version 15. I am trying to change the background color of the Actionbar and want to do this by changing the style and theme. I've tried many things but the background remains dark. Here is what my styles look like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#eeeeee</item>
</style>
```

In my manifext I set the application's theme to AppTheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default AppCompat support library uses value of `colorPrimary` attribute as a color of `ActionBar`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#eeeeee</item>
</style>
```

But if you want to make color of `ActionBar` be independent from primary color of theme, then you can set it like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/primary_teal_500</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Your second solution is what I was looking for. It looks virtually the same as  what I posted except when I set the parent for the ActionBar style to @android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar, it doesn't work. Your parent is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Use colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/LightColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/DarkColor</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: This does work but it raises the question as to what colorPrimary refers to. This will almost certainly change the color of a lot of other things that use this attribute and not just the Actionbar. Isn't there an attribute strictly for the Actionbar?

Comment: @AndroidDev you need create a style or use ActionBarSherlock library

Comment: But I did create a style as shown in my post. I shouldn't have to rely on some third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your style.xml file as follows and try,

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="android:background">#eeeeee</item>
    </style>
```

And your menifest as follows,

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Didn't work at all. Also, there is no theme called ''AppBaseTheme''. I had to use @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 0):

When using the Support Library, define the action bar like this:

res/values/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then apply your theme to your entire app or individual activities:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```